# Предложный падеж в именной части сказуемого

Tags: падежи, сказуемые

[http://rusgram.ru/предложный_падеж](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6)

> ... подобные выражения употребляются в позиции сказуемого (Он в гостях / на охоте)

Чего, чего? В предложении **Он в гостях** сказуемым будет **в гостях** ?? Разве это не обстоятельство места?

> Рассказ был о вечном.

Здесь **о вечном** именная часть сказуемого, верно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Он (где?) *в гостях / на охоте* - Вы правы, это обстоятельство места. Вы не поняли автора статьи, он не сказал, что это сказуемое: **употребляются в позиции** = **занимают место сказуемого**, потому что сказуемое пропущено, но на его существование указывает обстоятельство. Обратите внимание, автор рассказывает о таких конструкциях в части "**Обстоятельственные значения места**": *"Среди обстоятельственных значений предложного падежа центральное место занимают пространственные значения"*.

> Пространственная конструкция, в зависимости от семантики
> существительного, может обозначать нахождение в определенной ситуации,
> положении, пребывание в состоянии: в бою, в плену, в гостях, на охоте,
> на дуэли, на занятиях, в темноте, на ветру, в унынии, в отчаянии, в
> слезах, в шоке и т.д.

Речь идёт о семантике, не о синтаксисе.

*Рассказ был (о чём?) о вечном.* О вечном - дополнение.

> **Объектные** значения
>
> 2.2.1 Валентности содержания и темы
>
> За общим ярлыком «Объект», используемым в грамматиках для обозначения
> большой группы значений предложного падежа, скрываются разные
> семантические валентности (роли)

А дальше речь о семантике, не о роли в предложении.  Объектное значение у дополнения.

Comment: Спасибо. Просто, я думал, что если в словосочетании "рассказ о вечном" вечном это определение, то в "рассказ был/повествовал о вечном" определение автоматически преобразуется в именную часть сказуемого. Но это не всегда так. Скажем Скамья у дома (определение) и Скамья была у дома (обстоятельство)